# Filter an Excel table to show data for next Monday on a Friday in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have a lot of data which I filter everyday to build reports. I for example filter the table to show values for next week, this week, today and tomorrow. However, I'd like to also filter a table to show data for next Monday on a Friday. This is so I can prepare the data which is supposed to be shown for Monday after the weekend already on Friday the week before.

To filter by today, tomorrow, this week, next week I'm using

```
xlFilterToday
xlFilterTomorrow
xlFilterNextWeek 
xlFilterThisWeek
```

So I know that this might not be the most elegant way of sorting a table but it does the job

```
lastrow = Range("D" & startrow).End(xlDown).Row
ActiveSheet.Range("$B$7:$S$" & lastrow).AutoFilter Field:=7, Criteria1:=xlFilterThisWeek, Operator:=xlFilterDynamic
```

So I'm wondering if there is any way to change the

```
Criteria1:=xlFilterThisWeek
```

to something like

```
Criteria1:=xlFilterNextMonday
```

I've tried to look for a statement like that here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.xldynamicfiltercriteria

But with no success.

Help is highly appreciated, thanks.

Comment: You can use `Criteria1:=iif(application.weekday(date,vbMonday)=5, date+3,date+1)` instead of `xlFilterTomorrow`. Or you can simply count the date of next working day (e.g. skipping Monday holidays) beforehand, and apply by `Criteria1:=mydate`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately VBA does not offer anything close to `xlFilterNextMonday` (would be cool, though!). Maybe try something like:

```
Dim nextMonday As String

nextMonday = Format(Date + 8 - Weekday(Date, vbMonday), "dd/mm/yyyy")

ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$B$30").AutoFilter Field:=1, _
    Criteria1:=nextMonday
```

Result:

[image]

The reason for `Format(..., "dd/mm/yyyy")` is because VBA speaks American when interpreting dates, so you need to change your date format accordingly to match your source data (UK-format on my side).